# Proxy to Proxy communication

Tags: proxy-server, charles-proxy

We are using Charles Proxy to redirect requests from one system to another. For example if I need to send request from `A` to `D`, I send it through `B` where Charles Proxy is setup.

Now is it possible to forward all requests that come to Charles Proxy in `B` to another Charles Proxy which is setup in `C`.

`A` (knows only about `B`)---> `B` (Charles proxy, need to auto-forward to `C`) ----> `C` (Charles Proxy)-----> `D` (Final Destination)

Could you please let me know how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called External proxy setup in Charles which can do this. We just need to provide the information of external proxy to Charles and it will take care of forwarding the requests.

Answer (score 1):

In Charles, there is a feature called [Port Forwarding](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/port-forwarding/) that would help you to create such an architecture

Got to `Proxy -> Port Forwarding` and setup the first instance to go through the second one